# jQuery droppable not fired multiple droppable

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am trying to integrate jQuery droppable in my html document but whatever I try, the second droppable isn't fired.

My HTML is:

```
<div class="content">
  <div id="items1" class="span2 pull-left">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="items2" class="span2 pull-right">
    <div class="item">

    </div>
    <div class="item">

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My jQuery is:

```
<script>
            $( ".item" ).draggable({ 
                revert:true,
                start: function(e, ui)
                 {
                  $(ui.helper).addClass("ui-draggable-helper");
                 },
                 helper: function(){
                    $copy = $(this).clone();
                    return $copy;},
                 appendTo: "body"
            });
    $("#items1").droppable({
        accept: ".item",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            var servertype = ui.draggable.attr("servertype");
            if(servertype != "to"){
                copyMail(id,servertype);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#items2").droppable({
        accept: ".item",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            var id = ui.draggable.attr("id");
            var servertype = ui.draggable.attr("servertype");
            if(servertype != "from"){
                copyMail(id,servertype);
            }
        }
    });
  </script>
```

Dragging every item from #items1 on #items2 is working,
but every item from #items2 to #items1 isn't firing the drop event.

Is it a problem with the Z-Index or is it an other problem?

Thanks!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net <- fiddle please.

Comment: Here you go! Thanks! http://jsfiddle.net/JjUkK/2/